# How to write a program in python to run 5000 functions in a parallel manner?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing

I have a time-series data on which I've trained 5000 different regressors (models). Each model needs to predict, for 100 different categories, for each category 30 different subcategories, 200 values. i.e

Total number of time **predict** method runs is 5000 x 100 x 30 = 15,000,000

---

I have an idea that this can be done using parallel processing (each model's input doesn't depend on another's output). But, I'm not an expert in parallel processing.
**What would be the most efficient way to do the task?** 
Average time each function call will: 5-10 ms

Comment: Use a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) of workers. The easiest way is probably to use `map` or `imap`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert by any means either so take my answer with a grain of salt, should work though

```
from threading import Thread

threads_list=[]

for n, Func in ["list of functions here"]:
    exec(f'Func_{n} = Thread(target = Func, args = ("tuple of arguments here")')
    exec(f"Func_{n}.start()")
    exec(f"threads_list.append(Func_{n})")

for thread in threads_list:
    thread.join()
```

this runs each function in parallel as threads, then waits for each to be finished before carrying on with the rest of your code (that presumably relies on the output of these threads)